# Pull-back of a reflexive sheaf under a flat morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have seen the following statement being used in different papers but never saw a proof:

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a flat morphism between normal varieties and $\mathcal F$ is a reflexive sheaf on $Y$ (i.e. $\mathcal F^{\vee\vee}\cong\mathcal F$). Then the pull-back $f^*\mathcal F$ is a reflexive sheaf on $X$.

> Does someone know an easy way to prove this or a paper or book where it is proven?

Answer (score 5):

See Proposition 1.8 in

R. Hartshorne, [**Stable reflexive sheaves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01467074), *Math. Ann*. **254** (1980), 121-176. [ZBL0431.14004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0431.14004).

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straightforward statement. The point is that pull-back via a flat morphism commutes with the formation of $\mathscr H\!om$ (essentially because then the pull-back is exact).
So the pull-back of the dual is the dual, etc.